# Integrating RapidMiner process with Java

Tags: java, rapidminer

I need to run a RapidMiner process in Java. Like explained in this link :   [Integration of RapidMiner in Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834182/integration-of-rapidminer-in-java-application),

```
import com.rapidminer.Process;
import com.rapidminer.RapidMiner;
import com.rapidminer.operator.Operator;
import com.rapidminer.operator.OperatorException;
import com.rapidminer.operator.io.ExcelExampleSource;
import com.rapidminer.tools.XMLException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Object;

public class ReadRapidminerProcess {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

      RapidMiner.setExecutionMode(RapidMiner.ExecutionMode.COMMAND_LINE);
      RapidMiner.init();

      Process process = new Process(new File("C:\\Users\\Keshav\\.RapidMiner5\\repositories\\Local Repository\\lsvmtest.rmp"));
      process.run();

    } catch (IOException | XMLException | OperatorException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

After several modifications,I am stuck with the following error:

```
INFO: Process C:\Users\Keshav\.RapidMiner5\repositories\Local Repository\linsvmtest.rmp starts
com.rapidminer.operator.UserError: Cannot resolve relative repository location 'lsvmword'. Process is not associated with a repository.
    at com.rapidminer.Process.resolveRepositoryLocation(Process.java:1248)
    at com.rapidminer.operator.Operator.getParameterAsRepositoryLocation(Operator.java:1456)
    at com.rapidminer.operator.io.RepositorySource.getRepositoryEntry(RepositorySource.java:91)
    at com.rapidminer.operator.io.RepositorySource.read(RepositorySource.java:105)
    at com.rapidminer.operator.io.AbstractReader.doWork(AbstractReader.java:126)
    at com.rapidminer.operator.Operator.execute(Operator.java:867)
    at com.rapidminer.operator.execution.SimpleUnitExecutor.execute(SimpleUnitExecutor.java:51)
    at com.rapidminer.operator.ExecutionUnit.execute(ExecutionUnit.java:711)
    at com.rapidminer.operator.OperatorChain.doWork(OperatorChain.java:375)
    at com.rapidminer.operator.Operator.execute(Operator.java:867)
    at com.rapidminer.Process.run(Process.java:949)
    at com.rapidminer.Process.run(Process.java:873)
    at com.rapidminer.Process.run(Process.java:832)
    at com.rapidminer.Process.run(Process.java:827)
    at com.rapidminer.Process.run(Process.java:817)
    at ReadRapidminerProcess.main(ReadRapidminerProcess.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.symbol.JavaClass$JavaMethod.evaluate(JavaClass.java:362)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.handleMethodCall(ExpressionEvaluator.java:92)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.visit(ExpressionEvaluator.java:84)
    at koala.dynamicjava.tree.StaticMethodCall.acceptVisitor(StaticMethodCall.java:121)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:38)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:37)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:106)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:29)
    at koala.dynamicjava.tree.ExpressionStatement.acceptVisitor(ExpressionStatement.java:101)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.evaluateSequence(StatementEvaluator.java:66)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.java:77)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:47)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:246)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:220)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
```

Can someone please help out with the code?

Regards,

Keshav

Comment: Have you look at what is there? It is open source, or you are using RM 6? (In that case I guess you have support.)

Comment: Well,I looked through the RapidMiner forums, did some modifications... 
But the following error still exists:
'Cannot resolve relative repository location 'lsvmword'. Process is not associated with a repository.'
Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that RapidMiner cannot resolve the repository location used inside your `Retrieve` operator. The reason is that you have loaded the process from a file rather than from a repository. In fact, the process *is* stored in a repository, but the way you have loaded it, RapidMiner cannot know this. If you use this code to lode the process, it will be associated with a repository, and relative locatins can be resolved:

```
RepositoryLocation loc = new RepositoryLocation("//Repo/path/process");
Process process = new RepositoryProcessLocation(loc).load(null);
```