# rapidminer process in java code

Tags: java, rapidminer

I am working on sentiment analysis using rapidminer now i want to convert my rapidminer result into the java code using rapidminer api .please help me out from this issue i have stuck into the using .rmp file in process .

i have use preprocessing task within it i have use the document process operate 
which also contain the other four sub process like tokenize , filter token by length ,stem , and filter stopword .
        enter code here

```
this is my rapidminer xml code and its result: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true" height="636" width="668">
      <operator activated="true" class="text:process_document_from_file" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="76" name="Process Documents from Files" width="90" x="112" y="30">
        <list key="text_directories">
          <parameter key="negative" value="F:\fOR_FINAL_EXAM\dataset\for_database\Apex AD2600 Progressive-scan DVD player"/>
          <parameter key="positive" value="F:\fOR_FINAL_EXAM\dataset\for_database\Canon G3"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="encoding" value="windows-1253"/>
        <parameter key="prune_method" value="percentual"/>
        <parameter key="prune_above_percent" value="95.0"/>
        <process expanded="true" height="490" width="673">
          <operator activated="true" class="text:tokenize" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Tokenize" width="90" x="112" y="75"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:filter_by_length" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Filter Tokens (by Length)" width="90" x="216" y="162"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:stem_porter" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Stem (Porter)" width="90" x="292" y="247"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:filter_stopwords_english" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Filter Stopwords (English)" width="90" x="421" y="338"/>
          <connect from_port="document" to_op="Tokenize" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Tokenize" from_port="document" to_op="Filter Tokens (by Length)" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Tokens (by Length)" from_port="document" to_op="Stem (Porter)" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Stem (Porter)" from_port="document" to_op="Filter Stopwords (English)" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Stopwords (English)" from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="x_validation" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="112" name="Validation" width="90" x="313" y="30">
        <process expanded="true" height="472" width="311">
          <operator activated="true" class="support_vector_machine_linear" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="SVM (Linear)" width="90" x="112" y="30"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="k_nn" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="k-NN" width="90" x="112" y="165"/>
          <connect from_port="training" to_op="SVM (Linear)" to_port="training set"/>
          <connect from_op="SVM (Linear)" from_port="model" to_port="model"/>
          <connect from_op="SVM (Linear)" from_port="exampleSet" to_op="k-NN" to_port="training set"/>
          <connect from_op="k-NN" from_port="exampleSet" to_port="through 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_training" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_through 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_through 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
        <process expanded="true" height="472" width="311">
          <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Apply Model" width="90" x="51" y="56">
            <list key="application_parameters"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="performance" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="76" name="Performance" width="90" x="99" y="165"/>
          <connect from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="model"/>
          <connect from_port="test set" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Apply Model" from_port="labelled data" to_op="Performance" to_port="labelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Performance" from_port="performance" to_port="averagable 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_test set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_through 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_through 2" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="false" class="store" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Store" width="90" x="447" y="165">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="store"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="store" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Store (3)" width="90" x="112" y="300">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="data"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Process Documents from Files" from_port="example set" to_op="Validation" to_port="training"/>
      <connect from_op="Process Documents from Files" from_port="word list" to_op="Store (3)" to_port="input"/>
      <connect from_op="Validation" from_port="model" to_port="result 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Validation" from_port="averagable 1" to_port="result 2"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>

enter image description here]
```

this is my rapidminer result . as shown in images i wana get this result in my java code

Comment: So, you are asking for code in Java?

Comment: yes i m asking for code for java

Comment: Then its very unlikely you will get full code here done for you. SO is for problem solving, NOT `do this for me`.

Comment: i dont wana full code here i just wana some code or link which is help me to build this code in java.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of SO reveals [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834182/integration-of-rapidminer-in-java-application). Perhaps you could use this as the basis?

Comment: thanks u very much for ur reply i have already seen this example .. i need proper working example of it